# Why did it have to be snakes?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Hey, it's me, your favourite non-copyright infringing adventurer, Nindynana Nones! (No jokes please, my last film Kingdom of The Crystal Nana was enough of one to last us a while).

I'm on an wild venture deep in an ancient jungle and have arrived at the entrance of a mysterious tomb said to hold wonders untold (that's oxymoronic mysteries for you!), the door sealed tight. It seems the wise seers who carved these stones discovered Roman Numerals before The Romans.

> [image]

The moment I placed my hand on the sandy door, a large pit unfolded beneath my feet. I took my trusty kangaroo rope™ and swung to safety, narrowly missing the snarling bite of a scaled worm. These legless dragon noodles are vivid in colour and have what could only be described as *lizard tattoos*.

> [image]

They squirm together like living ramen, I don't care if they're cute, I'm not putting my hands in for a better look.

> I can still reach the door to press the stones, maybe entry can be gained **if I can enter the correct combination?**

HINT#1:

> The sum total of numbers in the combination is **28**

Comment: I'm living for the living ramen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The door**

> Some of the inscriptions seem potentially decipherable. For a particularly blatant example, the word "MIRROR" (fittingly, mirrored) can be seen over on the right. Other bits, mirrored or not, may possibly say things like "TIME(S?)" and "THIS" and "MUST". Aside from that MIRROR, though, none of it is clear enough for me to have much confidence about it. I remark that mirroring the Roman numerals yields legal but *different* Roman numerals.

**The snakes**

> There are seven of them, coloured at least kinda according to the traditional seven colours of the rainbow. In colour order:
>  *Red*: band (?)
>  *Orange*: WoW or MOM or something of the sort
>  *Yellow*: stars
>  *Green*: skull and crossbones
>  *Blue*: insect (?)
>  *Indigo*: HATER with arrows on both sides
>  *Violet*: hearts

**What to do**

> MOehm wisely suggests in comments that we extract numbers from those snakes' decorations, in the obvious rainbow order. It seems like there are a number of ways to do this, our further hint (the sum of the numbers) narrows it down a lot. There still seem to be a few roughly equally plausible interpretations; thanks to some nudging from OP, the intended one is evidently this:
>  R: **2** lines
>  O: **3** letters in "MOM"
>  Y: **5** stars
>  G: **1** skull-and-bones motif
>  B: **6** legs
>  I: **5** letters
>  V: **6** hearts
>  So I press 2,3,5,1,6,5,6 in that order. For the avoidance of doubt, "6" here means the button that initially looks like it says "IV" but is actually a mirrored "VI".

Comment: You've worked out a few pieces of the puzzle for sure, consider the door portion 'solved' as the two main things you mention are the only two needed to complete it. The the point about the snake colours is accurate and intended. I could say more but you're only steps from the  solution so I'd rather not spoil it :)

Comment: We need a combination, so each snake's tattoo could represent a number? The violet snake has six hearts (and the beetle has six feet). VI is only available when the buttons are mirrored, but the IV is then lost. Red might be II and yellow V, but other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: Darn. I thought the E was an F which if you Rot 1 (arrow 1 to the left) becomes  I  BUGS which leads to the blue snake somehow. Looks like I was wrong :(

Comment: @MOehm Ever play hotter/colder as a kid (or with your own kids)? You would be getting "you're on fire" yelled at you lol.

Comment: Well, the simplest way to follow MOehm's idea would be to count motifs on each snake. Red: two lines. Orange: one "WoW". Yellow: five stars. Green: one skull-and-bones. Blue: one bug. Indigo: five letters (?). Violet: six hearts. So maybe 2151156?

Comment: But much of that is conjectural enough that I'd be worried about entering a wrong combination and getting killed by rolling boulders, lightning strikes, sudden bursts of fire, etc.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan *you hear a rumbling noise and 5 loud bangs echo from within the tomb walls* It seems that 5 of 7 numbers are correct.

Comment: And I spoke to Orange, he's a mommas boy ;)

Comment: OK, so it's MoM rather than WoW. Perhaps I'm being dim, but that doesn't seem like it gives any more insight into what number might be meant. I suppose it could be 2 because it has two Ms. (Not that that's any different from "2 because two Ws", of course.) The other two obvious things to try, if experimentation doesn't kill me, are 6 for the bug (because 6 legs -- if indeed it is a bug) and/or 3 for the skull-and-bones (because three bits, one skull and two bones).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan If Indigo is 5, why would Orange be 1? Your new number for Blue is correct as was your original guess for Green.

Comment: As this is now turning into 'guess what number they represent' I've added the hint you suggested (that could've been part of the original puzzle, I'll update the artwork soon).

Comment: With your most recent edit, you have the combination right, just not all together ;)

Comment: Your second solution from 'So I suppose...' is correct, sorry this puzzle wasn't as polished as I thought before posting.